# Как в массиве записать значение после группы значений в этом же массиве

Tags: php

Имеется такой код:

```
Foreach ($_SESSION[explode] as $explode) {
 $tr[] =  '<td>'.
$explode[name].'</td>'
<td>'.
$explode[filial].'</td>'

}
```

Так вот как после группы значений `$explode[filial]`

Вот смотрите какой вывод нужен: т.к. в $explode[filial] содержится массив филиалов, то соотвественно

```
 Город1
 Город1
 Город1
```

Здесь ниже подбиваем итог и выводим этот же: `Город1`
Далее:

```
 Город2
 Город2
 Город2
```

Здесь ниже подбиваем итог и выводим этот же: `Город2`

И так далее.

Comment: Перефразируйте вопрос, приведите более подробный пример и входные данные. Пока совершенно непонятно что вам нужно

Comment: Готово, ещё раз добавлю выводится благополучно список однородных данных из массива, и нужно вывести в конце ровно 1 значение, равное названию из этой группы, а именно группы $explode[filial]

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, у вас в коде лишний апостроф между ''', а значит, он уже не выполнится в таком виде. 
Если $explode[filial] - массив, то я так понимаю, вам нужно что-то вроде

```
<?php
//Исх. даннные
$_SESSION['explode'] = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'test',
        'filial' => array(
            'test1',
            'test2',
            'test3',
        )
    ),
);

foreach ($_SESSION['explode'] as $explode) {
    $tr[] =  '<td>' . $explode['name'] . '</td><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $explode['filial']) . '</td>';
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста разъясните ибо вы в не то решение написали,

Comment: Просто объясняя даже по вашему примеру надо, чтобы не test выводил а конкретно например test1 или test2 или test3 внутреннего массива filial

Comment: Ну так по моему примеру он и выведет  test и test1, tes2, test3. Я может, чего-то не так понял, напишите хоть, какой html в итоге должен получиться на выходе

Comment: Значит ещё раз, имеется в массиве города: Город1, Город2, Город3 и тд.
в цикле foreach вывожу эти самые города тут всё ок, НО проблема появляется когда нужно вывести итоговый город т.е. подвести итог какие города были выведены
Значит ещё раз что должно быть на выводе
Из массива выводим города:
Город1 Город1 далее по сути идёт Город2 НО перед Город2 выводим одно значение Город1.
Вот добавлю в HTML формате :
<td> Город 1</td>
<td> Город 1 </td>
<td> Город 1</td>
<td> Город 1 </td>
</br>
<td>Итог:  Город 1</td> и тд...
<td> Город 2</td>
Итог Город2

Comment: Ок, тогда переспрошу. Зачем вам 4 раза выводить один и тот же город? (Я об этом `<td> Город 1</td> <td> Город 1 </td> <td> Город 1</td> <td> Город 1 </td>`)
И зачем нужно разделять ячейки таблицы через `</br>` (который к тому же `<br/>`), когда можно сделать 2 строки <tr>?

Comment: Мда вы к сожалению в корне не поняли проблему, представьте эксель отчёт, у вас есть МАССИВ городов: список сверху вниз, так вот когда ГОРОД1 Кончается нужно вывести это значение то есть ГОРОД1 далее идет по списку город2 и тд.